# Ubuntu screen goes purple then black on boot

Tags: wubi

I'm new to Ubuntu, and have not much experience with computers.

I installed Ubuntu with Wubi, all went correct, but when I'm on the screen to chosse Windows or Ubuntu, and I chosse, Ubuntu, the screen goes purple, with a text saying "Ubuntu" and some dots. Then it goes black, and I hear a sound. Nothing else happens.

I already searched a lot on how to fix this problem, but nothing works. I already tried the nomodset, but it dont works too.

I have HP Paviliong 6 Notebook PC, Windows 7, 4gb RAM, Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2450M CPU @ 2.50GHz  2.50GHz.

If you need some more info, say me!

Thanks!

*Edit - I already did that thing to run on Recovery mode too, it dont worked...*

Comment: Does pressing CTRL-ALT-F1 change something?

Comment: Nope, I did it on boot screen but it stay black. I tried when it was purple and changed nothing too.